# Readonly property overwriting in class extension

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to define some public readonly property which is readable and writable in the scope of object's method as following:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject

@property (readonly, nonatomic, strong) id foo; // <-- WHAT'S THE CORRECT WAY

@end

//

@interface MyObject () 

@property (readwrite, nonatomic, strong) id foo;

@end

//

@implementation MyObject

@syntesize foo = _foo;

@end
```

But when I type `@property (readonly, nonatomic, strong)` in Xcode it is never *helping* me to do it this way. Does it mean that I'm doing something wrong? Is the property flags order important? What approach is recommended to hide the implementation of property's writing capabilities?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of question this is. If it's a bug or a feature request just file a radar.

Comment: The question was rewritten to be more clear and specific. Could it be reopened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a commonly used and absolutely correct pattern. If you don't like the Xcode completion behaviour about it, you can surely file up a radar.